# Convert Array of arrays of objects to Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have to following array:

```
var arr1 = [
      [{n:"0.1",m:"m.0",other:"eg1"}],
      [{n:"1.1",m:"m.1",other:"eg2"}],
      [{n:"2.1",m:"m.2",other:"eg3"}]
    ];
```

And I would like to convert it to an array of arrays, as follows:

```
var arr1 = [
      ["0.1","0"],
      ["1.1","1"],
      ["2.1","2"]
    ];
```

I would like to convert to the other array only a few properties, not all of them.
Any idea how I can do this?

PS: I was using `flatMap` from another post but it does not work as it does not exist in Edge.

Comment: What about a for loop.

Comment: how is the second item in your arrays determined? Is it the index as a string? or the prefix of the `n` property, or the suffix of the `m` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the second value in each subarray is coming from the number after the period from the `m` key, you could use the map function to accomplish this:

```js
var arr1 = [
    [{n:"0.1",m:"m.0",other:"eg1"}],
    [{n:"1.1",m:"m.1",other:"eg2"}],
    [{n:"2.1",m:"m.2",other:"eg3"}]
  ];

var newArray = arr1.map(x => [x[0].n, x[0].m.split('.')[1]]);

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

For next time you have to put your attempts.

this is the solution for your problem

```
var arr1 = [
      [{n:"0.1",m:"m.0",other:"eg1"}],
      [{n:"1.1",m:"m.1",other:"eg2"}],
      [{n:"2.1",m:"m.2",other:"eg3"}]
    ];

arr1 = arr1.map(currentArray=>{
     const item = currentArray.shift();
     return [item.n,item.m.replace( /^\D+/g, '')] 
});
```